# Junit 3, start testing from a java method

Tags: java, junit3

I'm need to use JUnit 3, I know in JUnit 4 there is a method in the API to start the JUnit tests from a normal method in Java (Result r = org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(MyTestClass.class)). But how can I do this in JUnit 3 and getting the results of that?

edit:
I'm now doing it with this: TestRunner.run(MyTestClass.class);
But then I don't get any results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work: http://pub.admc.com/howtos/junit3x/junit3x.html#using_runners-chapt

Comment: I need to start the test from a Method. I call that method with velocity code. So I can't use Ant or Shell. And I want some feedback how the test were..

Comment: Just have a look in the what the Runners are doing.

Comment: Thanks! I get something now, not the exact result what I want. But I think I will come there where I want ;-)    int failures = junit.textui.TestRunner.run(runner.getTest(MyTestClass.class.getName())).failureCount(); (The result is now 1, but it needs to be 3)

Comment: Already found the stupid fault! I forget extends TestCase.. So stupid xD